# How can I fetch only object rows sent&mapped back from server when using RestKit+CoreData?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext, restkit-0.20

I am using RestKit 0.2.x with Core Data and following the standard tutorials, ie:

- Create Core Data model and use `mogenerator` to make code
- Instantiate object manager with base URL
- Create managed object context and persistent store
- Create entity mappings for all entities returned by my web service
- Create response descriptors for all web service endpoints and entities
- Add response descriptor to object manager

Everything seems to be "working" just fine ... I can call

```
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] getObjectsAtPath:_requestPath parameters:_requestParameters success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
    [self requestSuccess];
} failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    [self requestError:error];
}];
```

... all day long, and I then I keep handling with (as shown in the tutorials)

```
- (void)requestSuccess {
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [RKManagedObjectStore defaultStore].mainQueueManagedObjectContext;
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:_entityName];
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = @[_defaultSortDescriptor];

    NSError *error = nil;
    requestData = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

    [_delegate handleRequestSuccess:self withData:requestData];
    //[self cleanupRequestBeforeSuccessWithData:requestData];
    [self completeRequest];
}
```

Now the problem is that at least by default, RestKit+CoreData actually persists your GET'ted objects to its own persistence store, or something like that. I'll explain the "cleanupRequest..." in a moment.

That kind of defeats the purpose of trying to allow the users to specify parameters at the level of the web service client, because all of the objects seem to end up in the same place anyway.

For instance, let's say I have a method `/api/endpoint?queryString` and I call it with two different sets of parameters:

```
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] getObjectsAtPath:@"/api/endpoint" parameters:PARAMS_ONE success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
    [self requestSuccess];
} failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    [self requestError:error];
}];

[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] getObjectsAtPath:@"/api/endpoint" parameters:PARAMS_TWO success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
    [self requestSuccess];
} failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    [self requestError:error];
}];
```

If I then blindly follow the tutorials about how to retrieve my objects, my callbacks are then identical!

```
NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [RKManagedObjectStore defaultStore].mainQueueManagedObjectContext;
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"EndpointDataTransferObject"];
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = @["endpointDataTransferObjectID"];

NSError *error = nil;
requestData = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
```

The result, of course, is that the my `delegate` gets sent (pseudocode) `requestData WHERE PARAMS_ONE` on the first call, and then `requestData WHERE PARAMS_ONE UNION requestData WHERE PARAMS_TWO` on the second call.

Now all I really want is to be able to conduct the `NSFetchRequest` on *only those items mapped from the web service.* I think this is a totally reasonable expectation, so clearly I am missing something because whoever wrote this library is much more clever than I.

For instance, if I could somehow get an `NSArray` of all the objects from the two parameters it provides in the `success` block `(RKRequestRequestOperation *o, RKMappingResult *m)` - and if I can, **please tell me how!!!** - then my problem would be solved, and I could enjoy the caching without having to worry about whether my filters are being ignored.

What I do *not* want to do, however, is this:

- Call `getObjectsAtPath: parameters: success: failure:` with `parameters` and/or `path` representing a sort of "server-side" predicate
- On success, create a `NSFetchRequest` and a client-side predicate that mirrors my server-side predicate

This approach seems really really dumb, and yet, I don't know any better. But I refuse to do that. It is error-prone, redundant, and potentially resource-intensive.

So instead, I've opted to add a little method `cleanupRequestBeforeSuccessWithData` at the end of my `success` callback before calling `completion`:

```
- (void)cleanupRequestBeforeSuccessWithData:(NSArray *)managedObjects {
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [RKManagedObjectStore defaultStore].mainQueueManagedObjectContext;

    for (NSManagedObject *o in managedObjects) {
        [managedObjectContext deleteObject:o];
    }

    NSError *error = nil;
    [managedObjectContext save:&error];
}
```

This is ugly but it sure gets the job done. Now it totally empties the cache, but I'd rather have to make requests over and over again than to form "server-side" predicates with URL's *and then* form client-side `NSPredicate`s.

What am I missing about how this is supposed to work? Clearly, I'm missing something big.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I then blindly follow the tutorials

Never a good idea, you need to take what you've learnt from the tutorials and apply it to your problem space.

The items are indeed persisted as you're using Core Data. You don't need to but it does help with memory management. Technically you don't need to run a fetch because the mapping result (`RKMappingResult`) contains all the mapped objects, so you can just extract them and pass them on.

The other approach you shun of running a local fetch with filters is actually perfectly acceptable, and I'd say it's the usual approach as it's how a fetched results controller based approach works... To facilitate that you would add the query parameters to your mapping so that the mapped objects are updated. You do need to be cautious though as multiple requests returning the same objects could overwrite the data (assuming you're using unique identifiers).

Comment: Yep, that's what I ended up doing. I didn't know that the `RKMappingResult` would actually have the mapped objects in it. It was `[theResult array]` instance method that did

Comment: It's generally better to use the `dictionary` method as the array contain everything no matter what key path it was mapped from